# How to have hx-replace-url and hx-push-url replace params instead of appending?

Tags: url-parameters, htmx

I have a form like so:

```html
<form method="get" hx-get="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}" hx-target="#table-wrapper" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-trigger="keyup delay:200ms, change delay:200ms" hx-replace-url="true">
  {% comment %} some filters here {% endcomment %}
</form>
```

This is to allow django-tables2 tables to update dynamically, without having to reload the page.

The `hx-replace-url` isn't working quite how I'd expect.

If I navigate to `http://my.url.localhost:8000/some/path/` and start using my form, the url updates to have the params at the end of the url: `http://my.url.localhost:8000/some/path/?q=myquerystring&somefieldname=somevalue`, like I'd expect.

However, if I navigate to `http://my.url.localhost:8000/some/path/?q=myquerystring&somefieldname=somevalue` and start using my form, the new params are just appended to the end of the url: `http://my.url.localhost:8000/some/path/?q=myquerystring&somefieldname=somevalue&q=myquerystring2&somefieldname=somevalue2`

This is ugly for people sharing links around.

Is there some way to just replace the url params instead of appending them?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that behaviour because you're using the `request.build_absolute_url`. As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) states:

> If the location is already an absolute URI, it will not be altered. Otherwise the absolute URI is built using the server variables available in this request

That's why subsequent requests simply get parameters appended, not replaced. You can solve it by replacing the `hx-get` value with the `/some/path/` url (naming urls is Django's best practice, so consider using that instead).

```
<form method="get" hx-get="/some/path/" ....>
  {% comment %} some filters here {% endcomment %}
</form>
```